# Accessing multidimensional array php

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of data sent by jquery ajax to a php service:

```
  requestAjax = jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/ajax.salva-valutazione.php",
            data: {formdata:formdata, arrAccessori: arrAccessori},
        //  data:formdata,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(risposta){
               alert(".."+risposta);
             }
    });
```

In the php response page I use, if I do a print_r of all data:

```
 error_log(print_r($arrValutazione, TRUE) );
```

I get in error log:

```
  [formdata] => nome=John&cognome=Doe&indirizzo=My+address&citta=London&user_name=fedepupo&clienteID=1
```

While if I do

```
 error_log(print_r($arrValutazione['formdata'], TRUE) );
```

I obtain

```
nome=John&cognome=Doe&indirizzo=My+address&citta=London&user_name=fedepupo&clienteID=1
```

In error log.

My problem is how direcly accessing nome, cognome (...) values because if I try doing

```
 error_log(print_r($arrValutazione['formdata']['cognome'], TRUE) );
```

I get 'n', and also with

```
error_log(print_r($arrValutazione['formdata'][0]['cognome'], TRUE) );
```

I get the same value 'n'.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

> In error log.
>
> My problem is how direcly accessing nome, cognome (...) values because
>   if I try doing
>
> error_log(print_r($arrValutazione['formdata']['cognome'], TRUE) );
>
> I get 'n', and also with
>
> error_log(print_r($arrValutazione['formdata'][0]['cognome'], TRUE) );
>
> I get the same value 'n'.
>
> ```
> $arrValutazione['formdata'] =
> nome=John&cognome=Doe&indirizzo=My+address&citta=London&user_name=fedepupo&clienteID=1
> ```

Reason is you are accessing string not array, so you get always `n`

**Here is demo**

```
$ php -r '$string="abcdefgh"; 
  echo $string[0].PHP_EOL;
  echo $string[2].PHP_EOL; 
  echo $string["unknown_index"].PHP_EOL;'
a
c
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'unknown_index' in Command line code on line 4
a
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to get value of each variable

```
parse_str($arrValutazione['formdata'],$output);
print_r($output);
$nome = $output['nome'];
$cogname = $output['cogname'];
```

Similarily you can fetch any variable detail.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code,

```
parse_str($arrValutazione['formdata'],$formdata);
error_log(print_r($formdata['cognome'], TRUE));
```

Here is the reference link, http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: As rightly said by @AkshayHegde in his answer, the reason for your issue was that you are not accessing an array but a string.